# Need help changing Text of label in TS Code

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

On my html I have a label that shows a number of amount of images I have submitted to the server for the specific instance. My problem now is that when I upload images it does not refresh the image count, I have to close the Mobile application and open in up again to see image counter going up/.

I have tried to change the variable in the Typescript code after the images are uploaded successfully but the String does not change

```
<StackLayout class="m-10">
   <Label [text]="imagesCount + ' Photos Uploaded'" verticalAlignment="center" class="lbl-info" horizontalAlignment="center" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

```
get imagesCount() {
    this._imagesCount = workAttachments.length;

    return this._imagesCount;
}
```

I expect the Image Label to go from `0 Photos Uploaded` to `1 Photos Uploaded`

-- Edit --

This is how I upload my images

```
doFileUpload(file: any) {
        let actualFile = fs.File.fromPath(file);
        let base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(actualFile.readSync(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
        let workOrderAttachment = new WorkOrderAttachment(new Attachment(base64, file.replace(/^.*[\/]/, ''), 0), WorkOrderAttachmentType.PHOTO, '');

        this._service.workOrderAttachment(this.job.id, workOrderAttachment, ['id']).subscribe(result => {
            if (result == null) {
                UserInterfaceUtil.showError("Error Uploading images.", "");
            } else {
                UserInterfaceUtil.showInfo("Photos uploaded successfully.", "");
                this._imagesCount += 1;
            }
        }, error => {
            UserInterfaceUtil.handleError(error);
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm unsure how you are updating `workAttachments` array. If the updates take place within NgZone, then you should see the count updating already. We would need a complete example where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get this done correctly was adding a button on the Form to refresh the Label. It is not the best way of doing what I need, but it is done.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `get` property in TypeScript, you need to `return` a value.

```
public get imagesCount(): number {
    this._imagesCount = workAttachements.length;

    return this._imagesCount;
}
```

Check out the "Accessors" documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: But by default the accessor is public, you don't have to mention it explicitly.

Comment: Indeed @Manoj. I am used to specify the accessors, that is why I specified it.

Comment: Sorry @Eastrall, looks like the question was edited to include your fix, while I was comparing the code, I thought updating the accessors alone doesn't matter. It will be nice if people just vote when they make use of the answer.

Comment: I did change the code yes, the return value was still there.

What I have done now is to call the getter from the HTML and when uploading images, increase the variable in TS, but the Label's text still does not change. When I click on a button on the page, the label then change.

Comment: You can refresh your variable when your upload completes. I don't know how you upload your files, but if you use an observable, you can subscribe to it and refresh you variable. `uploadService.uploadFile(...).subscribe(result => refreshLabel());`